# nicEdit does not detect the 'space' character

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, nicedit

i'm having a problem with the [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) script. nicEdit is a javascript libray to set the html textareas of a webpage into Rich Text Format fields.

It works fine except that does not detect when i type the 'space' character. I google'd this and I didn't find any clue. I do exactly what is suposed to do to call the js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas({maxHeight:75}) });
</script>
```

Is someone having the same or similar problem, or know how to fix this?

**edit**: I tested it in Google-Chrome and Internet Explorer and the error persists in both.

Thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: do you have any online preview of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not solved but guessed the **cause** of the problem:

I made a simple html document only with a `textarea` and the javascript invocation of the question and worked fine.

So obviously was not a configuration problem, was some kind of **conflict with other javascript libraries** i'm using (**JQuery** and **jstree**). That is the reason i found nothing on google about it >_<.

My solution was change the nicEdit to [**jWYSIWYG**](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg), a jquery based RTF, and all works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, and solved it as follows:

**Problem:** 'space' wasn't registering in nicEdit fields

**Track-down:** The actual problem was that a jquery ui feature (accordion in this case) had registered the 'keydown' event for the editors parent. This prevents the 'keypress' event from propagating to the editors registered 'keypress' event handler. I didn't dig deep enough to know why it was only the 'space' key that was failing to propagate.

**Solution:** I removed the 'keydown' event from the editors parent. in my case that required the following snippet:

```
$(".accBar,.accContent").unbind('keydown');
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS reset?  That was my problem - baseline.reset sets some things, particularly revolving around "white-space: normal" that messed up rich text editors.  Primarily on windows only, even - so Firefox on mac will work fine, but Firefox on Windows will not be able to make space characters.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was most likely the jsTree hotkey plugin was intercepting spaces and calling "preventDefault".  See the issue here:

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/363

Removing the hotkey plugin or commenting out the space hotkey from jsTree should solve the problem.